# Improve loop efficiency

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have 21,000 rows that I'm pulling from a sqlite3 database, and I need to put it into a dictionary which is then appended to an array. This loop currently takes about 1.531 seconds, and I'm trying to minimize it as much as I can. What's a faster way that I can do this? (I am using python 2.7.3)

```
results = cursor.fetchall()
array = []
for row in results:
    a = {}
    b = row[11]
    c = str(row[8])
    d = str(row[9]) + " ? " + str(row[10])
    e = row[3]
    f = row[4]
    key = e + " - " + f

    rowToAdd = { 'aaa': row[3],
                'bbb' : row[0],
                'ccc' : row[1], 
                'ddd' : row[12],
                'eee' : row[2],
                'fff' : row[9],
                'ggg' : row[1],
                'hhh' : str(row[6]) + " (" + str(row[5]) + ")",
                'iii' : e,
                'jjj' : d,
                'kkk' : f
    }

    rowToAdd.append(array)
```

Is there a way to directly map a cursors output to a list of dictionaries with custom keys?

Is there a more pythonic way to do this that will speed it up?

Comment: Have your *SQL query* do the string concatenation and give each column a name. Then use a cursor that produces a dictionary for each row from that, and then all you have to do is `array = list(cursor)`.

Comment: for example 1. do not append, but pre-allocate the array and just fill it, saves unecessary creation/destroy of intermediatre stages 2. remove `dict` and use sth else (even simple `list`) should be faster

Comment: @NikosM.: the dictionary is not what is slow here; it is using literal syntax even.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, well sure, but still sth else (with no hashmaps) should be faster, for example a `list`

Comment: Cool I'll try giving these suggestions a shot, thank you!

Comment: @NikosM.: The difference between creating a Python `list` object (which is a dynamic array) and a `dict` is negligible here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave concatenations to SQLite instead, and use the [`sqlite3.Row` row factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) instead, which gives you an object that can be used both as a tuple and a dictionary.

Have your query name the keys by using column aliases:

```
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT 
        col3 as aaa, col9 as bbb,
        col6 || ' (' || col5 || ')' as hhh,
        col9 || ' ? ' || col10 as jjj
    FROM SOME_TABLE
''')
```

then simply use that result instead of building a new list. If you *must* have a list with these you can just use:

```
array = cursor.fetchall()
```

or

```
array = list(cursor)
```

but you probably would be better of iterating over the results as you need to have access to the rows.